# Raise event after 30 seconds of no user interaction

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm programming a WPF application, and I'd like to raise an event if the user has not interacted with the program for 30 seconds. That is to say, no keyboard or/and mouse events.

The reason I want do do this is because I want to bring attention to the screen if a variable `alertstate` has been set to true.

I'm thinking of using something along the lines of `BackgroundWorker` but I really don't know how I can get the time a user has not interacted with the program. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I guess this question basically comes down to checking if a user has interacted with the screen. How do I do this?

Comment: Create a timer set at 30 seconds, raise alert when it's done, and (the tricky/annoying bit) reset it on each user interaction.

Comment: you refer to user interaction as a mouse movement or a key pressed?

Comment: How do you know if the user is reading the screen or not? ;-p

Comment: @jelies , yeah... I guess I could write some custom code to check for key presses/mouse movement...

Comment: You could probably use Rx for this, which could be cleaner than manually managing a timer.

Comment: @Jodrell They shouldn't be reading the screen, they should be busy fixing the problem >_>

Comment: And who says they aren't fixing the problem, lol. Maybe they have to ask someone something, or maybe he is writing something down, or maybe he is being interrupted by someone (maybe you?)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to record the last time the user moved the mouse or pressed a key and then check if that time is greater than your threshold.

So you need to add mouse move, mouse click and keyboard handlers to your application (this is Silverlight code so you might have to change namespaces etc.):

```
private void AttachEvents()
{
    Application.Current.RootVisual.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(RootVisual_MouseMove);
    Application.Current.RootVisual.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(RootVisual_KeyDown);

    Application.Current.RootVisual.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, (MouseButtonEventHandler)RootVisual_MouseButtonDown, true);
    Application.Current.RootVisual.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseRightButtonDownEvent, (MouseButtonEventHandler)RootVisual_MouseButtonDown, true);
}
```

Then in the handlers have code like this for the mouse move:

```
private void RootVisual_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timeOfLastActivity = DateTime.Now;
}
```

and a similar one for the `KeyDown` event handler.

You will have to set off a timer:

```
idleTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
idleTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
idleTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(idleTimer_Tick);

// Initialise last activity time
timeOfLastActivity = DateTime.Now;
```

Then in the tick event handler have something like this:

```
private void idleTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now > timeOfLastActivity.AddSeconds(30))
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any version to do this in `winforms`?

Answer (score 7):

One way you could do this is to use GetLastInputInfo. This information will give you the time elapsed (in ticks) since last user interaction on mouse/keyboard.
You can have information here : 
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo
So have a timer which checks for the last time an interaction went on. If you need accuracy, you can either check each 5 second for example OR you can, when you see that idle is ongoing for y seconds (y<30), setup a one-time timer that will check for idle time after (30-y) seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Use `ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle` and `DispatcherTimer` to achieve this.

```
DispatcherTimer timer;

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += new EventHandler(ComponentDispatcher_ThreadIdle);
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do your action here
    timer.Stop();
}

void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: A thread being idle does not imply the user being idle. and a user being here, the thread can still be idle...

Comment: On the contrary - if a user is interacting with the program, the ComponentDispatcher thread is busy handling the windows messages associated with the user's input. The opposite is true though. It's possible that the ComponentDispatcher will be _busy_ even though the user isn't there.